# ExtJS getSelection only able to pass a max record count of the stores set page size

Tags: javascript, extjs

So I have a grid that contains a store with a set page size of 500. This store exists for the recordStatusGrid, like so:

```
var store = Ext.create("Ext.data.Store", {
autoLoad: false,
model: "DataStatusEntry",
remoteFilter: true,
buffered: true,
pageSize: 500,
remoteSort: true,
isLoaded: false,
}
```

I have a button handler that passes to another component which grabs all the selected records to pass to the back-end. Here is the button:

```
iconSvg: 'execute',
text: "Execute",
itemId: "executeBtn",
type: "record",
multiple: true,
scope: this,
handler: function () {
      var button = Ext.getCmp("executeRecordButton");
      button.handler(button, "recordStatusGrid");
}
```

The component "executeRecordButton" is what grabs all the selected records for processing.

```
text: "Execute",
itemId: "execute",
id: "executeRecordButton",
cls: "x-btn-text-icon",
iconSvg: 'execute',
disabled: true,
handler: function (button, gridId) {
   var grid = Ext.getCmp(gridId);
   var selection = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection();

// some more processing stuff here
```

The problem is, if I load 800 records into the GUI and then select them all to execute, the button only passes the first 500 and my selection variable contains 500 records. As per my store page size. If I change the page size to 600, it will contain 600 records.

I'm trying to find why getSelection() does not actually get all selected and caps out at the page size, even though my gui will load more records (if I scroll down far enough) and my GUI allows me to select more records. Is there a way to ignore the page size when getting the selected records? The docs haven't been helpful here.